# Are there ways to measure "how much power did "Russia" lose when the Soviet Union broke up?"

Tags: russia

Russia today is the largest country in the world (by a fairly wide margin). That is true after the other 15 or so "Socialist Republics" left and went their separate ways in 1991, leaving Russia with a bit more than three quarters of the former Soviet land area. If physical size were the main determinant of power, Russia would not have lost all that much.

Another measure of Russia's lost power is the decline of population. Here, the loss was more serious, because Russia was left with only about half of the population of the former Soviet Union. And today's Russia seems to be a shadow of its "former" (Soviet) self.

So is one fourth (based on land) or one half (based on population) a better (rough_ guess of the decline in Russian power when the Soviet Union broke up? Are there any other other measures of power (e.g. GDP, nuclear warheads, troop strength, Nobel Prize winners, or any other relevant power source) that might provide a better estimate of Russia's loss?

Comment: I don't think Nobel Prize winners (especially in Literature) are a good way to measure power :)  Also, GDP is not a good way to measure power of USSR vs. RF, since the changes in GDP likely had more to do with non-breakup issues.

Comment: Power can't be compared across time without hefty assumption and extrapolation; the world is constantly changing, and the Soviet Union would have been changing as well. Russia may be "weaker" in some relative terms (e.g. share of global GDP, men under arms), but so are the United States and Europe, with the rise of China and the other emerging economies, even though they are stronger in some other terms. And once you invent a mechanism for the USSR to remain intact, you venture into alternative history.

Comment: @choster - Tell that last one to Putin :)

Comment: @Choster: I'm not trying to go into alternate history. I'm trying to estimate a "pro forma," which investment bankers do all the time, when estimating the effects of restructuring a company. Put another way, did the decline in Soviet power, and the resulting increase in the safety of the U.S. make "star wars" worth it?

Comment: IMO the global commodity price boom must be part of any explanation of Russia's relatively benign fate in the past few decades. BTW, do you really think "star wars" (as in [Strategic Defense Initiative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_Defense_Initiative)) had anything to do with the end of the Soviet Union? I'd argue (with my technology hat on) that its ambitions were clearly unfeasible at the time, and expert Soviet scientists would have seen that too.

Comment: Just think of all those Olympic medals that are now achieved by former USSR republics...

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski:That's the point I was trying to make. +1 for the comment.

Comment: @TomAu - the decline in Russian power per se wasn't the goal of Star Wars. Tactically, the goal was the qualitative ability to change the MAD equation. Strategically, it was removal of a threat of a global power combining Russia's natural resources and population with European non-natural (economic etc... resources), done by Russia taking control of Western Europe. The latter was **temporarily** achieved.

Comment: @DVK As the originators of the GDI idea described, the goal was actually to make the USSR to spend more than the US so to undermine their economy. They were well aware they will not eliminate MAD.

Comment: @Anixx do you have sources for them being well aware other than in hindsight?

Comment: @Anixx - that was the immediate method, not the end goal

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There was a serious drop in GDP. The following graphic shows drop in GDP per captia for Russian Federation (not the USSR):

[image]

Passengers transported by civil air transport (RSFSR compared to Russia):
[image]

<sub>([source](https://malchish.org/images/stories/avia/rosaviatia.jpg))</sub>

Passengers transported by intercity rail transport:
[image]

There was also a serious drop in demographic indicators. The following plot shows birth rate (red), death rate (black) per 1000 citizens for Russian Federation:

[image]

For a longer period:

[image]

There was an increase in crime rate (red=murders, green=drugs-related crimes):

[image]

Number of drugs addicts:
[image]

Growth in tuberculosis rate (red=Russia, green=Ukraine): 
[image]

Average wage in kilograms of potatoes:
[image]

Comment: The question is how much of the impact did the **break up of USSR** had on any of these charts, vs unrelated causes (e.g. if they would have stayed the same if USSR didn't break up)

Comment: So this might average out to [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) percent loss overall, right? :)

Comment: OOC, where did these numbers come from? I ask because I was repeatedly told back in the 80's that you couldn't really get accurate GDP numbers out of communist countries because they didn't have a market economy to measure. What I heard from Russians at the time was "We pretend to work, and they pretend to pay us". So I'm wondering how much of the old 80's numbers were "pretend" GDP.

Comment: @T.E.D. I will try to find the source of the graphic, but you can find a similar graphic on the site of Andrey Illarionov, former Russian president advisor and now an opposition politician: http://aillarionov.livejournal.com/383615.html Note that his graphic shows *ratio* of the GDPs per person of Russia and the USA (USSR in red, Russia in blue).

Comment: @T.E.D. you can also find many useful graphics here: http://www.pavelhulko.ru/?cat=13 and here: http://rpp.nashaucheba.ru/docs/index-102059.html

Comment: @T.E.D. Some other graphics: GDP, transportation http://toyota-club.net/files/lib/z_st/11-06-01_lib_postcris/p8.png Industrial output: http://toyota-club.net/files/lib/z_st/11-06-01_lib_postcris/p1.png From here: http://toyota-club.net/files/lib/z_st/11-06-01_lib_postcris.htm Another plot (GDP per captia for USSR/Russia, China, Brzil, India): http://www.fcos.ru/userfiles/104/image/119/119-03.gif with reference to http://www.conference-board.org/data/

Comment: @T.E.D. Wage per kg Potatoes is a pretty solid measure from publicly available and verifiable statistics.  What you were told, regarding economics, is wrong in two cases: firstly, the Soviet Union possessed internal "white" markets of various sorts; secondly, it is possible to measure GDP for any society with value-form circulating (as the USSR had), even if there's fudge in some sectors like production for Military purposes.  Base sectors, like IIa (reproduction of labour) are difficult to fudge because they're representable as wages versus potatoes, for example.

Comment: These effects is from the economic-political collapse of the Soviet block, more than the breakup of USSR, and they would have happened even without a breakup.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro this is wrong, Soviet dependence on the other Socialist countries was minimal, mostly it was the USSR who provided economic help. On the other hand, the economic connections between Soviet republics inside the USSR were very tight. Many plants simply could not produce anything with new borders, for example, the RAF in Riga and many aircraft factories. Also the breakup of the USSR led to legal nihilism, separatism and ethnic conflicts.

Comment: @Anixx Who talked about "dependence"? I sure didn't. "Many plants simply could not produce anything with new borders" - Trade was not made impossible by these borders. What happened was that post-USSR production was out-competed in price, quality, speed and flexibility by the rest of the world. So the problem was not that new borders arose, but that the wall around the Soviet block fell.

Comment: To amplify @TED's comment, a lot of dramatic shifts in statistics like this can be attributed to changes in reporting (in this case, less motivation to suppress bad news for political/ careerist reasons).

Answer (score 6):

I doubt whether one can expect any meaningful overall quantitative evaluation on this topic (also given the background of external commodity price index rises during that time).

For instance, how would one quantify the effects of Russia's [brain drain](http://www.economist.com/blogs/easternapproaches/2012/11/russian-politics)? Sure, one could start by multiplying some average-income-plus-cost-of-education with the known number of emigrees. One [Sergey Brin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergey_Brin) (Сергей Михайлович Брин) was born in Moscow: so would we have to subtract (say half of) Google's [stock value](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GOOG) from Russia's current mineral wealth? Besides, who may know in which countries exactly the oligarchs' giant fortunes may currently reside? An what is the real "monetary" cost of being led by a former KGB officer (some say in the mold of [Yuri Andropov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Andropov))?

So with that I think any real answer to Russia's relative gain or loss has to be a qualitative one, despite what investment bankers do all the time :)

Comment: There is a common Russian joke: "Why don't we have an Elon Musk here in Russia?!" -- "Because if Musk were a Russian, he would have been still serving a prison term for PayPal".  This illustrates the importance of liberties for prosperity. It is not obvious that had Brin remained in Russia, he would have created Google there.